# Django How to add data to database from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, database

I am have created a page in django, on this page I have create a button that calls a JavaScript function which in turn gets data from a API. This part of my code works as expected as it writes the response data to the console. However I cannot seem to get that data to be inserted into the model I have created in django.

I am not sure how python/javascript/models are meant to all link together.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Set(models.Model):
    scry_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    set_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    card_count = models.IntegerField()
    block_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    parent_set_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    digital_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    foil_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nonfoil_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**sets.html**

```html
{% extends "main/index.html "%}

{% block content %}
  <div class="background card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="btn" id="setRefresh" style="border: 1px solid" onclick="setRefresh()"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>

    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock%}
```

**custom.js**

```js
function setRefresh() {
  const Url="https://api.scryfall.com/sets";
  fetch(Url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => obj = data.data)
    .then(() => obj.sort(function(a,b){return a.released_at.localeCompare(b.released_at);}))
    .then(() => {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        //console.log(obj[i].name);
      }
    })
}
```

**view.py**

```
def sets(request):
    return render(request,
                  "main/sets.html",
                  {"Sets": Set.objects.all})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two missing parts. First you need to have a `url` to  listen for changes and then you need to have a `view` function where you want to set data. And you need to make some changes for the `JS` part of your code.Example below can clear this up and it is functional as well:

```
views.py

@ajax_required
def views_name(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_id = request.POST.get('post')
            YourModel.objects.create(id=post_id)
    except Exception:   # pragma: no cover
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^whatever/$', views.views_name, name='whatever'),
]
```

```
custom.js:

$(function () {
    $(".class-name").click(function () {
        var csrf = $(this).attr('csrf');
        var post = $(this).attr('page-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/whatever/',
            data: {
                'post': post,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
                },
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            success: function (returned_values) {
                // do whatever you want after success!                
                },
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it

1. Method 1 : After retrieving the data, send them to your django app instead of logging them into the console . have a django view that handles the corresponding request coming from your js code containing the data then adding them to the db. In other words you should fetch again , but this time to your django app using a post request .

.Your view should look like this :

```
    from .models import Set
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import json
    
    def save(request):
        data=json.loads(request.body)
        for entry in data:
            s = Set()
            s.scry_id=entry["scry_id"]
            #in the next lines you map entry fields to Set fields



            s.save()
         return HttpResponse("ok")
```

2. Method 2 : Your button call your django app on click , then your django app retrieve the data from https://api.scryfall.com/sets itself then save them to the db. Your code should look like this

   ```
   from .models import Set
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   import json
   import requests

   def save(request):
       response = requests.request("GET", "https://api.scryfall.com/sets")
       data=response.json()
       for entry in data:
           s = Set()
           s.scry_id=entry["scry_id"]
           #in the next lines you map entry fields to Set fields



           s.save()
        return HttpResponse("ok")
   ```

Of course in either case don't forget to map your urlconf to the save view

Comment: I have added the view in method two called `setrefresh`, however I am unsure what you mean by `button call your django app` and when I try to add `path('sets', views.setrefresh(), name="setRefresh"),` to my `urls.py` it runs on page load rather than on the button click.

Comment: I meat by that : the onclick callback of your button should fetch to url url of your django app. also you should use  path('sets', views.setrefresh , name="setRefresh") instead of path('sets', views.setrefresh(), name="setRefresh") . it is running on page load because you were already invoking it by saying views.setrefresh()